# Do not scroll page down when spacebar is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you may know some browsers have this default functionality to scroll page down when spacebar is clicked. I usually like this feature, but due to nature of my website I need to get rid of it.

I've been using

```
      window.onkeydown = function(e) {
          return !(e.keyCode == 32);
      };
```

which eats all spacebar functionality and gets the job done, however if user is typing in a comment or a search query and they press spacebar no space is added in a text as this functionality has been eaten up.

So is there a way to disable just the scrolling part and leave all other functionality as it is?

Comment: Either catch the events that happen on input fields/textareas and stop them from bubbling up to window; or check the event target in your global event handler.

Comment: @CBroe Thing is that some bits of page use iFrames from external websites e.g. disqus commenting system, and I can't catch events from those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    return !(e.keyCode == 32 && (e.target.type != 'text' && e.target.type != 'textarea'));
};
```

Comment: again, will this work if I'm using commenting system like disqus, which is based on iFrames, so comment for is loaded from their website not mine?

Comment: try `window.parent.onkeydown ... ` from an iFrame

Comment: this code does not have access to iframe thus will not affect it

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
          if(e.keyCode == 32 && e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "BODY") e.preventDefault();
      };
```

Comment: Still gets scrolled down ;/

Comment: works here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kq9kw/  maybe try to find a better target as window or document

Answer (score 0):

Probably need to equalise for IE:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;
    var elem = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    if(e.keyCode == 32 && elem.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "BODY") {
        evt.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
};
```

(untested)

But you would need to attach an event to/within each iframe, using `iframeref.contentWindow`.

After the page and iframes have loaded you could loop through the `frames[]` collection.